# Поменять столбцы местами в матрице

Tags: java

При работе с матрицами, а именно с двумерным массивом назовем его `int[][]a` для замены строк мы можем сделать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                var temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

В этом случае все просто, и работоспособно. Но можем ли мы сделать что то подобное со столбцами? Я пытался сделать вариант `var temp=a[][i]` или что то подобное, не компилятор выбивает ошибку.Есть какое-нибудь лаконичное решение данной проблемы, как на примере выше со строками?

Comment: Боюсь что нет. Столбцов физически не существует, это элементы в разных массивах. Можно бегать по индексам, либо пересмотреть логику отображения. Кстати, этот код меняет каждую строку с каждой строкой? Это точно нужно?

Comment: @defaultlocale да, в моей функции есть логика которая сортирует по возрастанию строки, по конкретному столбцу, и меняет их местами.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь что простого лаконичного решения нет, т.к. столбцов физически не существует, это элементы в разных массивах.

Можно написать метод, который будет менять столбцы местами:

```
private static void swapColumns(int[][] a, int first, int second) {
    //меняем элементы в каждой строке
    for(int r=0; r<a.length; r++) {
         int temp = a[r][first];
         a[r][first] = a[r][second];
         a[r][second] = temp;
    }
}
```

И затем уже использовать его:

```
for...
    swapColumns(a, i, j);
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы поменять местами строки, циклы вообще не нужны. А вот чтобы поменять местами столбцы, один цикл придется использовать:

```
// Строки х и у меняются местами
var tempRow = a[x];
a[x] = a[y];
a[y] = tempRow;

// Столбцы х и у меняются местами
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var tempCol = a[i][x];
    a[i][x] = a[i][y];
    a[i][y] = tempCol;
}
```